# Parsing this kind of data

Tags: perl, object

I have written a wrapper for an API. Previously I'd worked on simple string-based GET requests to PHP scripts using Perl.

As part of analysing the response, I have to analyse the following data which appears to be an object. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to extract usable data from this.

`print Dumper` on the data returns this:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
         '_rc' => '200',
         '_request' => bless( {
                '_uri_canonical' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://example.com/?list=1&token=h_DQ-3lru6uy_Zy0w-KXGbPm_b9llY3LAAAAALSF1roAAAAANxAtg49JqlUAAAAA')}, 'URI::http' ),
                '_content'       => '',
                '_uri'           => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri_canonical'},
                '_method'        => 'GET',
                '_headers'       => bless( {
                       'accept-charset' => 'iso-8859-1,*,utf-8',
                       'accept'         => 'image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png, */*',
                       'cookie'         => 'GUID=cHoW3DLOljP4K9LzposM',
                       'user-agent'     => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0',
                       'authorization'  => 'Basic YWRtaW46bmljb2xl',
                       'cookie2'        => '$Version="1"',
                       '::std_case'     => {
                         'cookie' => 'Cookie',
                         'cookie2' => 'Cookie2'
                               },
                       'accept-language' => 'en-US'
                     }, 'HTTP::Headers' )
              }, 'HTTP::Request' ),
         '_headers' => bless( {
                'client-peer'   => 'myip:8085',
                'content-type'  => 'text/plain',
                'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
                'connection'    => 'keep-alive',
                'client-date'   => 'Sat, 18 Jul 2015 12:41:00 GMT',
                '::std_case'    => {
                  'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num',
                  'set-cookie2'         => 'Set-Cookie2',
                  'client-date'         => 'Client-Date',
                  'client-peer'         => 'Client-Peer',
                  'set-cookie'          => 'Set-Cookie'
                },
                'client-response-num' => 1,
                'content-length' => '8684'
              }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
         '_msg' => 'OK',
         '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
         '_content' => '{"build":30470,"torrents": [
            ["043CC5FA0C741CDAD9D2E5CC20DF64A4A400FA34",136,"Epi.S01E03.720p.HDTV.x264-IMMERSE[rarbg]",690765843,39,26951680,671744,24,0,0,0,"",0,1454,0,114,2436,1,663814163,"","","Stopped","512840d7",1437022635,0,"","/mydir/Epi.S01E03.720p.HDTV.x264-IMMERSE[rarbg]",0,"0368737A",false],
            ["097AA60280AE3E4BA8741192CB015EE06BD9F992",200,"Epi.S01E04.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]",221928759,1000,221928759,8890308649,40059,0,0,0,"",0,1461,0,4395,65536,-1,0,"","","Queued Seed","512840d8",1437022635,1437023190,"","/mydir/Epi.S01E04.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]",0,"8F52310A",false]],
            "label": [],"torrentc": "350372445"
            ,"rssfeeds": []
            ,"rssfilters": []
            }
         ',
         '_msg' => 'OK',
         '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1'
       }, 'HTTP::Response' );
```

I would like to extract each of the following strings from the returned object

```
097AA60280AE3E4BA8741192CB015EE06BD9F992
200
Epi.S01E04.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]
```

Unfortunately, my understanding of objects in Perl is very elementary.

The original code which returns this data looks like this:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->get( $url, @ns_headers );
print Dumper($response);
```

How can I work on the strings that of interest?

Comment: You're looking at an `HTTP::Response` object, and the correct way to access data from it is to call its *methods* as described in [the module documnetation](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [documentation for `HTTP::Response`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response), you will see that there is a `content` method, which will return the content of your HTTP message, and a `decoded_content` method that does the same but also decompresses the data if it happens to be compressed (in your case the data is uncompressed.)

In this case it looks like the content is encoded as JSON data, so you will also need to load the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module to decode it into a Perl data structure

For example

```perl
use JSON 'from_json';

my $content = from_json $response->decoded_content;
my $torrents = $content->{torrents};

for my $torrent ( @$torrents ) {
  say for @$torrent[0,1,2];
  say '';
}
```

#### output

```
043CC5FA0C741CDAD9D2E5CC20DF64A4A400FA34
136
Epi.S01E03.720p.HDTV.x264-IMMERSE[rarbg]

097AA60280AE3E4BA8741192CB015EE06BD9F992
200
Epi.S01E04.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]
```

Comment: You want `decode_json`, not `from_json` (or `decoded_content` instead of `content`).

Comment: What different effects?

Comment: @melpomene: `decoded_content` returns the body of the message decompressed according to the method specified in the `Content-Encoding` HTTP header. `decode_json` decodes a UTF-8-encoded JSON string. Neither are applicable here

Comment: Not quite true; `decoded_content` also decodes text according to the content [`charset`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Message#mess-content_charset). The point is that JSON-over-HTTP is almost universally UTF-8 encoded and you somehow need to handle that `content` returns bytestrings but `from_json` takes unicode text.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1 says you're supposed to use UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32, and I've never seen the latter two in the wild.

Comment: This message has no `Content-Encoding` header and no `charset` on the `Content-Type` header. Even the content type is a simple `text/plain` instead of `application/json`. The `HTTP::Response` object returns `US-ASCII` as the content charset. Nothing would be gained by your measures, but I will consent to a change to `decoded_content` as it can't do any harm unless the message happens to specify an unknown encoding