# How to retrieve data from this nested array?

Tags: json, perl

I'm having a hard time retrieving data from a nested array. The result of converting a HTTP::Response to JSON results in the following Dumper result:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'FE93DEC4505772CE9CFCE353A1F07027A165032F',
          [
            [
              'myshow.S01E03.HDTV.x264-ASAP.mp4',
              192494228,
              192494228,
              2,
              0,
              735,
              bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              -1,
              0
            ],
            [
              'Downloaded.txt',
              172,
              172,
              2,
              734,
              1,
              bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
              -1,
              -1,
              -1,
              -1,
              -1,
              0
            ],
            [
              'myshow.s01e03.hdtv.x264-asap.nfo',
              4798,
              4798,
              2,
              734,
              1,
              $VAR1->[1][1][6],
              -1,
              -1,
              -1,
              -1,
              -1,
              0
            ]
          ]
        ];
```

I wish to print out the list:

```
myshow.S01E03.HDTV.x264-ASAP.mp4
Downloaded.txt
myshow.s01e03.hdtv.x264-asap.nfo
```

and also get 'FE93DEC4505772CE9CFCE353A1F07027A165032F' into a string variable.
I'm having a hard time figuring out what can do this.

My code upto this point:

```
my $response = $ua->get( $url, @ns_headers );
my $content = from_json $response->decoded_content;
my @files=$content->{files};
print Dumper(@files);
```

Comment: Parsing means converting from a data format into an in-memory data structure. You're already successfully parsing it. You just seem to lack any knowledge of how to deal with arrays and references. Have you tried anything? http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html make for good starting points.

Comment: I don't know if that's necessarily fair - a simple array of arrays isn't hard to parse, but this isn't. It's an array containing some array refs, and some that aren't, which is rather more complex than the basic case.

Comment: This is different from the data in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492440/parsing-this-kind-of-data). Are you using a different API?

Comment: @Borodin. It's the same API, but a different method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` denotes an array in Perl. This is a 3 deep array. So you need to iterate it, extracting values.

```
foreach my $element ( @files ) {
   if ( ref $element eq "ARRAY" ) {
       foreach my $subelement ( @$element ) { 
           print $subelement->[0],"\n";
       }
   }
   else { 
      print $element,"\n";
   }

}
```

This process is complicated a little by *not* being an array of arrays - it's actually rather a messy data structure. So you need to use something like `ref` to tell if you're looking at an array now, or a text element.

One of the useful tricks to know here is - if you have an array, you access a value by `$array[0]`. If you have an array reference you can use `->` which dereferences the array first.

E.g.

```
my @array = qw ( fish ); 
my $ref_to_array = \@array;
print $ref_to_array,"\n";
print $ref_to_array -> [0],"\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining with actual code! I wasn't familiar with this kind of nested structure.

Comment: I had to go one more level deeper to get the data. I submitted an edit to the code.

Comment: @Droidzone Sobrique's code works with the data you posted in your question, so your proposed edit doesn't really make sense. Future visitors to this post could be confused if the code in the answer weren't consistent with the data in the question.